# how to get the id of a div when using jquery hasClass method?

Tags: jquery

This code is not working:

```
$("div").hasClass("testSection").attr("id");
```

I get the following error message:

> TypeError: $(...).hasClass(...).attr is not a function

Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: `.hasClass("testSection")` returns true or false, that's why it does not work. do you want to select the div with the class `testSection`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is because `hasClass()` returns a boolean, not a jQuery object. Hence calling `attr()` on a boolean results in the error you're seeing.

Assuming there is only one div with the specified class you can use the class in the selector:

```
var id = $("div.testSection").prop("id");
```

If there are multiple divs with the class, you'd need to loop:

```
$("div.testSection").each(function() {
    var id = this.id;
    // do something with the id...
});
```

Answer (score 5):

`.hasClass("testSection")` returns a boolean. It doesn't return a jQuery object to chain.

Also you do understand that when matching multiple elements, using specific function like `.attr` would return from the first selected element.

```
$("div").attr('id'); => $('div').eq(0).attr('id');
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$("div").filter(".testSection").attr("id");
```

[`hasClass`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) will return a boolean (true/false), rather than a jQuery object that has an `attr` function.

Answer (score 2):

hasClass will return true or false not object, use this,

```
$("div.testSection")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to get all of the ids of a set of elements, you'll need to iterate over them using a for construct, or jQuery's each function. I also recommend using prop() over attr(), though in this case it wouldn't matter much:

JSFiddle example:
http://jsfiddle.net/turiyag/QXyWV/1/

```
$.each($("div.foo"),function(index,value) {
    log($(value).prop("id") + " ");
});
```